# SharePoint Server 2013 installation error

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I installed SharePoint Server 2013 on windows server 2008 r2 sp1.Back end Sql 
  Server 2008 r2. I installed Products Prerequisites and Share point Server
  successfully.But when I run The Products configuration wizard I got this error.
             Failed to create sample data.An exception of type  System.UnauthoriedAccessException was 
   thrown.Additional exception information:0x80070005
   Accessdenied .

Answer (score 0):

The issue will be with access to SQL server/database. Can you confirm, that databases are created? SharePoint_Config_xx, SharePoint_AdminContent_xx, and WSS_Content?

Comment: In SQL Server the above mentioned databases are not created.

Comment: The 8th step of products configuration ran for some time and error occured.@Lukas Nespor

Comment: Does your account (that is running Configuration Wizard) has permissions to SQL? Server roles: dbcreator and securityadmin

Comment: My account:Sathesh,(Username).How can this account give permission to SQL.Please help@Lukas Nespor

Comment: Yes.The account that is running Configuration Wizard has permissions to SQL.What I did.SQL Server Management Studio->Security->Logins->ComputerName\Satheesh->Properties->ServerRoles->dbcreator,public and security admin @Lukas Nespor

Comment: Were you able to run the configuration wizard without any error?